# How to fix hole in yard with/from burst irrigation pipe?

Tags: pipe, pvc, hole, irrigation

I had the end cap crack on a 2" irrigation line buried 1-2' underground. It sprayed downwards, clearing away 2' of dirt vertically (3-4' total downward now). I found an area about 3-4' away from this site that also had water rushing up from it, so there is at least a 3-4' deep horizontal hole as well, all within feet of my patio and pool pump cement block.

How do I fix this?

I live in Tampa, FL. Ground is kinda of a dry clay/sand kind of dirt.

Right now, my idea is to carefully dig up where I think the hole is so that there's no cavity down there. Flush the broken line. Re-PVC-glue it was a new end cap. Refill hole it with some clay/compact dirt filler.

Schematic:

```
                  1'wide hole            2" hole
---------------------      --------------  ---------
                    |      |             | |
          1-2'  ======]    |             | |
                   /  X     \     3'     | |
                  /          ------------| |
                 |                         |    X is side of crack
             4'  --------------------------| 
                           estimated cavity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your suggestion/idea is the solution. Unfortunately, when it comes to filling in earthen holes with earth, it's a very simple operation involving digging tools and excess clean fill.

Personally would excavate around and fix the broken end cap, and backfill. It's no more complicated than that.

TL:DR = Grab a shovel and order some dirt.

Comment: Done and done, thanks for the confirmation! I was nervous at first b/c I had to remove some trees and the proximity to the house, but DIYed it. Dug up the area, confirmed the cap had cracked..sawed it off and replaced it. Took 8 extra bags of dirt fill to pack the hole back up. I almost filled with gravel but read it was a bad idea that could worsen erosion.

Comment: Congratulations! Going slow and doing things by hand in cases like this are often the safe and conservative way to do things. I'm sure you're glad it's done.